# line it up next to each other (nummbers)?

Tags: python, for-loop

so i do not want the results under each other. How can i line it up next to each other? Like 1 1 1 and not 1 under 1 under 1. I did not find any good information about that. I tried print(x,t) but it do not work for for loops or does it?

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW9Fe.png)

Answer (score 2):

By default, `print()` appends a newline character to the end of the string.

To have it not do this, simply use the following:

```
print("Hello World!", end = "")
```

Comment: okay thx. but how to use it for loops ( see picture "here")

Comment: @sixdu It works the same way in loops